Error "SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5" while loading model from TF 2.18 in Tensorflow.NET
I trained a model using Python 3.12 and tensorflow 2.18.0 :
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
> 2.18.0

I saved the model using tf.saved_model.save(model, "model_SavedModel/") to have a SavedModel format compatible with TensorFlow.NET (as .h5 is not supported).
When I try to use it in Dotnet using _model = tf.keras.models.load_model(modelPath); I get this error :
Unhandled exception. System.NotImplementedException: SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model, please use higher version or submit an issue to https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET/issues. to let us know you need it.
   at Tensorflow.Keras.Saving.SavedModel.KerasLoadModelUtils.load(String path, Boolean compile, LoadOptions options)
   at Tensorflow.Keras.Saving.SavedModel.KerasLoadModelUtils.load_model(String filepath, IDictionary`2 custom_objects, Boolean compile, LoadOptions options)
   at Tensorflow.Keras.Models.ModelsApi.load_model(String filepath, Boolean compile, LoadOptions options)
   at dotnet_launcher.ModelLoader.LoadModel(String modelPath) in /app/PredictClass.cs:line 19
   at dotnet_launcher.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 39

As you can see above, the model is saved in Tf 2.18, which is above 2.5.
If I try to use model.save("malware_SavedModel") instead, I get this error :
ValueError: Invalid filepath extension for saving. 
Please add either a `.keras` extension for the native Keras format (recommended) or a `.h5` extension. 
Use `model.export(filepath)` if you want to export a SavedModel for use with TFLite/TFServing/etc. 
Received: filepath=trained_models//malware_SavedModel.

However, the model works fine while importing in Python.
How can I save my model in a format that is accepted by TensorFlow.NET ?

Keras 3 no longer supports saving models with model.save(). Instead, use the .export() method to save your model in the TensorFlow SavedModel format. Additionally, consider upgrading your TensorFlow.NET to the latest version, as newer versions may offer better compatibility.
